# Charset problems for custom tags for jsp in Netbeans

Tags: file, jsp, netbeans, tags

I want to create a layout.tag file in NetBeans, but NetBeans doesn't support creating files with this type of extension. After just copying an empty layout.tag file into my directory in NetBeans I then wrote my code, but NetBeans didn't allow me to save it with normal encoding and parsed my special letters into rubbish-looking letters, and encoded the file ISO-8859-1.

However, when I write my code in a notepad, save it somewhere else, and then copy it into my directory project (not in the IDE), the encoding stays the same during compilation in NetBeans. This means for sure that it's IDE's problem. I had the same problem with saving a FreeMarker file (NetBeans changed it's encoding to ISO-8859-1). Installing a plugin helped then but I haven't seen any plugin for .tag files.

Is there a way to fix it?

Ps. Yes, I have <%@tag description="layout" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> in my file.
Ps 2 Yes, I added -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 into NetBeans config file
Ps 3 Yes, Sources of my projects are set to encoding utf-8

I'm so fed up with that, I may even change IDE